# template specialization of a auto_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, templates

Maybe I'm overcomplicating things, but then again, I do sort of like clean interfaces.  Let's say I want a specialization of auto_ptr for an fstream - I want a default fstream for the generic case, but allow a replacement pointer?

```
 template <> 
 class auto_ptr<fstream> {
     static fstream myfStream; 
     fstream* ptr; 

 public: 
     auto_ptr() { 
         // set ptr to &myfStream;
     }
     reset(fstream* newPtr) {
         // free old ptr if not the static one. 
         ptr = newPtr 
     };
  }
```

Would you consider something different or more elegant?  And how would you keep something like the above from propagating outside this particular compilation unit?

[The actual template is a boost::scoped_ptr.]

EDIT:

It's a contrived example.  Ignore the fstream - it's about providing a default instance of object for an auto_ptr.  I may not want to provide a specialized instance, but would like to keep the auto_ptr semantics for this static default object.

```
class UserClass { 
public:
    auto_ptr<fstream> ptr; 
    UserClass() {  }
}
```

I may not provide an dynamic object at construction time - I still want it to have a meaningful default.  Since I'm not looking at ownership-transfer semantics, it really shouldn't matter that my pointer class is pointing to a statically allocated object, no?

Comment: You seem to be conflating two concepts - that of an autopointer and that of a default stream. That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: +1 to Neil. Specializing auto_ptr this way would completely change its semantics: how would anyone using auto_ptr<fstream> know that the default value is not NULL ?

Comment: Also the question is that... since you are bound to reimplement it completely when specializing, why not giving it another name ?

Comment: Could you show a use case that you have for this?

Comment: @UncleBens: the use case I'm specifically thinking about is a pointer to a QIcon.  I want the value in my program to have a default value, that can be overridden at run-time.  Contrived, example, and perhaps bad design... but I'm asking about plausibility.

Comment: @Chris a better solution is to provide access to the pointer only through functions. And if the pointer is empty (`NULL`), then you return a pointer to your fall-back instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wouldn't end up good. The biggest problem is that std::auto_ptr deletes the underlying object in its destructor. This means your default parameter can't be static. The only choice you can make is to do a lot of hacks there and IMHO the price you'll pay while maintaining all that crappy code isn't worth the small advantage you'd have.

Comment: I'd probably typedef it, and auto_ptr was a based choice, boost::scoped_ptr would probably be a better basis.

Answer (score 1):

That looks reasonable to me, could be confusing if it's use is widespread in a codebase and not documented though.

I notice you are being carful, but I'm going to stress it anyway: make sure you don't double-free your static object!

Comment: The alternative is creating an auto_ptr and assigning a default value and then reset()ing it's value later, or do it in the constructor.  I know where I'd rather have it be done.

Answer (score 1):

You might get something that compiles and works, but I wouldn't do that if I were you.

Boost defines certain functionality for the construction of an `auto_ptr`. If you redefine that somehow, you have violated their specification.

Invent a name for your new functionality, make it a factory function, and don't worry about specializing someone else's template.

**EDIT:** deriving from `auto_ptr` is another option, if you're really set on changing initialization semantics:

```
tempate < class T, T *d > 
struct defaulted_auto_ptr
    : public auto_ptr< T > {
    defaulted_auto_ptr( T *p = d ) throw() : auto_ptr<T>( p ) {} // set default
    defaulted_auto_ptr( auto_ptr<T> &r ) throw()
        : auto_ptr<T>( r ) {} // allow conversion
    template< class O > defaulted_auto_ptr( auto_ptr<O> &r ) throw()
        : auto_ptr<T>( r ) {}
};

fstream default_file;
typedef defaulted_auto_ptr< fstream, &default_file > file_ptr;

auto_ptr< fstream > baseptr = file_ptr(); // can assign to auto_ptr, but unsafe
```

I'm a little doubtful of the cost-benefit tradeoff of this, but it's better than entirely reimplementing `auto_ptr`.

You still have to figure out what to do if a defaulted object is destroyed. `default_file` above will be `delete`d, potentially many times.

Comment: Except it's not really a factory.  The idiom is that I have a pointer, and it want it to have a known default value.  It can be changed at any time.  I suppose I can take care to simply assign a default value, but it's something I'd rather have done in a constructor.